# /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'overlay'

Tags: linux, debian, grub, mbr

После установки Windows на жесткий диск с Linux, у меня полетел MBR. Я поискал-поискал, и нашел способ поставить на место GRUB командой "grub-mkconfig". Я прописал две команды в Live системе, и вот, что я писал:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

и на выходе я получаю

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `overlay'.
```

Как это решить? Или это я пишу неверные команды?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grub хочет перенести настройки live диска. Войдите в систему и восстанавливайёте уже там.

```
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt/

. /etc/profile
grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub2
```

Answer (score 0):

Для восстановления GRUB потребуется загрузочный диск или флешка с дистрибутивом Linux. Итак, вы загрузились в Live-режиме. Теперь нужно открыть терминал.

1.Нужно определить раздел диска, на котором был установлен GRUB `fdisk -l`.

2.Например установлен в `/dev/sda`,  примонтируем корневой раздел, выполняем команду (вместо /dev/sda вы должны указать свой раздел):`sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt`. Если для загрузчика у вас выделен отдельный раздел, то нужно примонтировать еще и его (вместо /dev/sdX укажите ваш boot-раздел):`sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt/boot`

3.Посмотреть содержимое директории /mnt, чтобы убедиться, что мы примонтировали верный раздел:`ls /mnt`.

4.Нужно создать ссылки на несколько директорий, к которым GRUB должен иметь доступ для обнаружения всех операционных систем. Для этого выполните команды:`sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`.Если у вас используется UEFI, то еще нужно примонтировать EFI-раздел в директорию /mnt/boot/efi :`sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi` например...

5.Для генерации файла конфигурации GRUB используется команда `update-grub`. Данная команда автоматически определяет файловые системы на вашем компьютере и генерирует новый файл конфигурации. Выполняем команду:`sudo update-grub`.
Если вдруг утилита update-grub не определила ваш Windows ,то можно будет запустить update-grub повторно уже из вашей Linux-системы, когда вы в нее загрузитесь (мне это помогло и Windows определился).

6.Осталось выполнить установку GRUB на диск. Мы определили раздел на котором у нас установлен GRUB на первом шаге данного руководства. Это раздел /dev/sda.

Для установки GRUB используется команда `grub-install`, которой нужно передать в качестве параметра диск, на который будет выполняться установка (в моем случае это диск `/dev/sda`):`grub-install /dev/sda`.

7.Выходим из окружения chroot: `exit`.

8.Отмонтируем все разделы, которые мы примонтировали:`sudo umount /mnt/sys sudo umount /mnt/proc sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts sudo umount /mnt/dev`. Если вы монтировали boot-раздел, то его тоже нужно отмонтировать:`sudo umount /mnt/boot`.Если вы монтировали EFI-раздел, отмонтируем:`sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi`.Отмонтируем корневой раздел:`sudo umount /mnt`.

9.Перезагружаем компьютер:`reboot`.

Если во время перезагрузки компьютера меню GRUB не появилось, то это еще не значит, что он не восстановился. Возможно, просто установлена нулевая задержка и меню не показывается. Чтобы показать меню GRUB нужно во время загрузки, после того, как появился логотип материнской платы:
`удерживать клавишу Shift, если у вас классический BIOS`; `нажать Esc, если у вас UEFI`.

Если у вас, при выполнении grub-update, не определился Windows и не был добавлен в меню GRUB, то уже загрузившись в вашу систему Linux (не LiveCD), откройте терминал и выполните:`sudo grub-update`.