# /usr/sbin/grub-probe error failed to get canonical path of overlay

Tags: grub

Полетели грабы на всех дисках.
Загружаюсь с Live CD, перехожу в корневой каталог одного из дисков (операционная система та же, что и live cd - kali linux), пишу `mount -o bind /папка папка` для всевозможных папок.
Пишу: `update-grub2`. Выдаёт эту ошибку. На `update-grub` и на `grub-install \dev\sda` выдаёт ту же ошибку.
В чём дело?

---

Итак, я загружаюсь с live cd (кали линукс). Пишу: `fdisk -l`.
Вот вывод:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA HDWD110 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfdbc877c

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EADS-00M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x74a06618

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 1920071679 1920069632 915.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1920073726 1953523711   33449986    16G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1920073728 1953523711   33449984    16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdc: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SUV400S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 85B08BFA-9E54-41EB-9E75-7FA6E6687677

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 234440703 234438656 111.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdd: 233.56 GiB, 250785824768 bytes, 489816064 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Glide 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 489816063 489814016 233.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/loop0: 3.22 GiB, 3460136960 bytes, 6758080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

---

Вот, что касаемо UEFI:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220363/usr-sbin-grub-probe-error-failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-overlay](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220363/usr-sbin-grub-probe-error-failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-overlay)

Comment: @InDevX пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: все равно продолжает выдавать ошибку?

Comment: @KoVadim пишу `mount /dev/sda /mnt`, а мне выдаёт `mount: /mnt: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy`. Просто проблема за проблемой, опять вопрос задавать. Уже цепочка получается. К слову, я попытался это решить, но пока не получилось(

Comment: с вероятностью 99.99% mount /dev/sda /mnt - неверная команда. нужно монтировать разделы по отдельности То есть, где то так mount /dev/sda1 /mnt (циферка там меняется в зависимости от Вашей картины)

Comment: @KoVadim тогда в длинном ответе к тому вопросу, который мне выше скинули, что-то неправильно. К слову, короткий ответ тоже не сработал.

Comment: а там не сказано использовать /mnt/sda - там скзано взять тот раздел, куда установлено.

Comment: @KoVadim ну я и с sdb пробовал.

Comment: sdb - это диск. а на нем будут разделы sdb1, sdb2 и так далее. Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: @KoVadim я это знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim вот ещё насчёт этого. Я устаналивал убунту, сейчас вопробовал установить линукс минт. Ни у того, ни у другого не удалось установить граб. И, к слову, на момент установки ни там, ни там нет интернета.

Comment: очень интересно. может у Вас какая то совсем нестандартная штука. Например, в биосе включен строгий UEFI?

Comment: @KoVadim дополнил вопрос.

Comment: у меня было такое, grub не хотел видеть uefi. Видимо Вам придется внимательно перечитать это https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI , а потом подумать о таком `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda`. Но это все маловажно, пока Вы нормально не примонтируете все и chroot не сделаете

Comment: @KoVadim вот как я в этом вопросе монтировал - нормально?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288454/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81-live-cd

Comment: вначале нужно примонтировать корень, потом, обычно boot, за ним монтируют другие папки (но это в случае особых конфигураций, рядовому домашнему пользователю максимум бывает нужно /home подмонтировать). А этого всего там нет. Что в этом случае будет с chroot, я не знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim всё оказалось довольно прозаично. Дело было в том, что я не создавал загрузочный диск с помощью .iso образа, а просто копировал файлы из него на флешку. Но работало ведь! По крайней мере частично...

Comment: в режиме UEFI как раз и можно сделать загрузочную флешку, просто скопировав нужные файлы